# Unable to make qgis build in cmake

Tags: qgis

I am trying to build qgis without any change in source code which i have downloaded from github using clone and i have download OSGEO4W from qgis.org and the same is installed in c drive.

I have installed cygwin, cmake, OSGEO4w, mysys,python34, pyqtgpl, MinGW, QT5.5, qt creater, visual studio 2010 express.

Can any body share his cmake which has build successful.

I was able to configure cmake and generate. But I am getting 13 build failed in MSV 2010.
Im following the same path as give in source code procedure on qgis.org.

Can somebody help me out.

Comment: It's been a while since I did this but I don't think QGis works with Python 3 yet. Also if you include an actual error it will give us more clues